# Bundler.with_clean_env does not find a JavaScript Runtime

Tags: heroku, bundler

I try to create a simple **heroku** app which clones a git repository, invokes `bundle install`, a `rake dist` task and then uploads the created files to a GitHub repository. The build task of the cloned repository uses *Rake Pipeline*, which uses the `execjs` gem for building the binary.

I've created a sample app located at https://github.com/pangratz/github-uploader-test, which illustrates the problem. The directory structure of the application is the following:

```
/upload.rb
/project
   Rakefile
   Assetfile
   Gemfile
   Gemfile.lock
```

The app itself is a simple *sinatra* app with a `get '/'` route, which looks like this:

*upload.rb*

```ruby
get '/' do
  Dir.chdir "project" do
    Bundler.with_clean_env do
      system "bundle install"
      system "bundle exec rake dist"
    end
  end
end
```

For demonstration purpose, the `project` folder simulates the cloned git repository. It contains a `Rakefile`, `Assetfile`, `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.

*project/Rakefile*

```ruby
desc "Build"
task :dist do
  Rake::Pipeline::Project.new("Assetfile").invoke
end
```

*project/Assetfile*

```ruby
require "rake-pipeline-web-filters"
require "json"
require "uglifier"
require "execjs"

puts ExecJS.eval "'red yellow blue'.split(' ')"
```

*project/Gemfile*

```ruby
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "rake-pipeline", :git => "https://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline.git"
gem "rake-pipeline-web-filters", :git => "https://github.com/wycats/rake-pipeline-web-filters.git"
gem "colored"
gem "uglifier", :git => "https://github.com/lautis/uglifier.git"

group :development do
  gem "rack"
  gem "rest-client"
  gem "github_api"
  gem "ember-docs", :git => "https://github.com/emberjs/docs-generator.git"
  gem "kicker"
end
```

The invocation of `bundle install` seems to work. The problem is that `rake dist` is failing with the error `Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.`.

The heroku app itself is created with the option `--stack cedar`.

I've also created a route '/test' which uses `Execjs` and this does not fail. So it seems 
that there is a problem with the `Bundler.with_clean_env` and not finding the installed JavaScript Runtime ...

*upload.rb*

```ruby
get '/test' do
  puts ExecJS.eval "'red yellow blue'.split(' ')"
end
```

Comment: That's funny. I can reproduce it on Heroku, but not locally. Adding `therubyracer` to project/Gemfile fixes it, but I'm at a loss as to why ExecJS finds a JS runtime (Node I presume) in the main project, but not in the subproject. If you really need this fixed, I would suggest diffing the output of `env` and similar things between main project and subproject.

Comment: Yeah, it's working locally for me too. I'll try your suggestion diffing `env` ... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue on Heroku and I could solve the issue. The problem was that the `Dir.chdir("project")` in combination with the `Bundler.with_clean_env` resulted in an invalid `PATH` which is needed to locate the JavaScript Runtime. Long story short, here is the working solution:

```ruby
get '/' do
  Dir.chdir "project" do
    Bundler.with_clean_env do
      ENV["PATH"] = "/app/bin:#{ENV['PATH']}"
      system "bundle install --without WATWAT"
      system "bundle exec rake dist"
    end
  end
end
```

A note on the solution: the `--without WATWAT` is needed because Heroku installs your app with `bundle install --without development`. Since the `--without` is remembered for successive calls, and the gems of `development` group are needed in the `Assetfile`, this option has to be overwritten. Using `--without ''` somehow doesn't work so I'm using the nonexistent group `WATWAT` to include all groups in the `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']=/path/to/project/Gemfile`. That should ensure that install and exec find the correct Gemfile.

Comment: Is this different to `bundle install --gemfile /path/to/project/Gemfile` ?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how I would use your suggestion? Should I keep the `Bundler.with_clean_env`?